# Question about determining a basis for a vector space $V$.

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

Okay so say I want to find a basis for a vector space $U$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^3}$. Where $V$ is a spanning set of $U$ and $$V=\{[-1,3,1],[0,1,3],[-1,2,-2],[1,2,14]\}$$

my question is does it matter how you set up the matrix you do row operations can you make a $4\times3$ matrix where each row is a vector in $V$ or does it have to be a $3\times4$ where  each column is a vector in $V$?

Obviously the basis would be different when it's in RREF but would the dimensions be the same and would it actually be a basis whichever way you did it?

Thanks.

Comment: Actually, turns out you could simply pick any two of the given four vectors, they form a basis

Comment: I didn't spot that to be the case how so? Also can you answer my main question as well please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce rows in
$$V{\text{ = }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  { - 1}&3&1 \\ 
  { - 1}&2&{ - 2} \\ 
  0&1&3 \\ 
  1&2&{14} 
\end{array}} \right)$$
by using famous Gauß-Algorithm.

Then you will find, that you may take these two vectors
$$\begin{gathered}
  a = {\text{(1}}{\text{,0}}{\text{,8)}} \hfill \\
  b = {\text{(0}}{\text{,1}}{\text{,3)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}$$
as basis for $U$.